# Output a JSON in NodeJS, file name problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fs, writefile

I want to out put a JSON with a lot of items. Here is a function I implemented with 7 parameters.

```
let OutputJSON = (testName1,result1,timeStart1,timeEnd1,SEL1,URL1,day) =>{
        var resultOBJ;
        resultOBJ = {testName:testName1, result:result1, timeStart:timeStart1, timeEnd:timeEnd1, SEL:SEL1, URL:URL1};
        var resultjson = JSON.stringify(resultOBJ);
        console.log(timeStart1);
        var fs = require('fs');
        fs.writeFile( `${testName1} ${day} ${timeStart1} Result.json`,resultjson,(err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Output no problem');
          });
    }
```

I call this function in another script.

```
var Test1 = function(testcase){

    var testData = testcase
    var folderName = 'broadband'
    var fileName = testData.caseName;
    var screenShotPath = `screenshots/${folderName}/${fileName}`;
    var testResult=false;
    var startTime = currentTime();
    var endTime;
    var day = currentDate();

    describe(`Test Case: ${testData.testname}`, function(){
        this.timeout(40000);
        this.slow(1000);

        before(function*(){
            prepareScreenshotDir(folderName, fileName);
            nightmare = Nightmare(testSetting.nightmare);
            d = {
                width: 1024,
                height: 1200,
            }
            if (testSetting.authentication) {
                yield nightmare.authentication(testSetting.authentication.user, testSetting.authentication.password);
            }
            yield nightmare
                .goto(testData.URL)
                .size()
                .then((dimension)=>{d= dimension;});

            yield takeFullScreenshot(nightmare, d, `${screenShotPath}/${fileName}-${stepCounter}.png` );
        });

        beforeEach(function*(){
            yield nightmare
                //.click('#__tealiumModal')  //wts that?
                .catch(error=>{
                    console.log(testData.testname + ' Landing page fail.');
                    testResult=false;
                });
        });

        after(function*() {
            // End the Nightmare instance
            yield nightmare.end();
            endTime = currentTime();
            console.log(startTime,endTime,day);
            // OutputJSON(testData.testname,testResult,startTime,endTime,1,119,day)
            OutputJSON(testData.testname,testResult,startTime,endTime,testData.SEL,testData.URL,day);
        });

        it('Check page', function*(){
            yield nightmare
                .wait(testData.SEL) // Coverage search box
                .then(() => {
                    console.log( testData.testname + ' Landing page is loaded.');
                    testResult = true;
                    endTime = currentTime();
                  })

            var d = yield nightmare.size();

            yield takeFullScreenshot(nightmare, d, `${screenShotPath}/${fileName}-${++stepCounter}.png` );
        });
    });
}
```

The OutputJSON() is called in the after function. The problem is in the startTime paramter. The time start can be passed into the OutputJSON() as the starttime is able to be passed to the resultOBJ, but in the fs.writeFile part,if I include  ${timeStart1} since I want the output JSON title include the time, the fs function will not be called. NO JSON will be output. If i delete the ${timeStart1}, then the JSON can be output successfully. It becomes 'PASS_CASE 2019-09-10 Result.json' without the time.

I try to use  fs.writeFile( `${timeStart1} Result.json` to shorten the name as I doubt that it is a problem of length of file name, but actually it is not. The JSON file still can not be output.

I also try to check is it a problem about input parameter type. But I now can ensure that the item passed into the function, both day and time are string. Then why I can put the day into the title, but I can not put the time. I dont understand. Here is the gettime and getdate function I implemented:

```
let currentTime = function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var d_string = d.toString();
    var d_substring = d_string.substr(16,8);
    return d_substring;
}


let currentDate = function(){
    var d = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);  
    return d;
}
```

I want the time can be put in the output JSON title .
Thank you so much for reading this. I am sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I have some new update. Now it logs an error :Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\robert.lui\Desktop\test2\PASS_CASE 2019-09-10 12:27:23 Result.json' .

Comment: but when I do not put in timestart1, even if in the folder there is no a JSON that match the name , it will create a new one. Why when I have the timestart1 in the title , there will be an error?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. The problem is cause by the ":" character in the time string. /, >, <, |, :, & are characters that will cause the issue.

```
let currentTime = function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var d_string = d.toString();
    var d_substring = d_string.substr(16,8);
    d_substring = d_substring.replace(':','_');
    d_substring = d_substring.replace(':','_');
    return d_substring;
}
```

Replace the : with _, problem solved.